# mysql query array inside array

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

sorry first for my lousy english ... but i got some question need some advice

how can i get data from database in one query?isit possible get array from db, inside the main array got another array?

table structure:

```
user_post - 
    id int(12) AI unique
    uid int(12)
    content text

user_image - 
    filename varchar255
    uid int(12)
    pid int(12) index
    pid->foreign_key user_post.id 
    ON DELETE CASCADE
    ON UPDATE CASCADE
```

example:
for each user_post can contain more than 1 row user_image but maximum 10 row, how can i select and make it all together in 1 array so i don't need to run query 2 times like below?

query 2 times to done this example:

```
$db = new Db('main');
$db->query('SELECT `id`, `uid`, `content` FROM `user_post` WHERE `id` = :id LIMIT 1');
$db->bind(':id', '1'); //Example
$result = $db->single();

$db->query('SELECT `filename`, `uid`, `pid` FROM `user_image` WHERE `pid` = :pid LIMIT 10');
$db->bind(':pid', $result['id']);
$images = $db->resultset();
```

so the $images will contain all the images filename for the post, anyway to make it in 1 query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this in only one query, by [`JOIN`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_%28SQL%29)ing the two tables:

```
SELECT p.id, p.uid, p.content,
  i.filename, i.uid, i.pid
FROM user_post AS p
INNER JOIN user_image AS i ON i.pid = p.id
WHERE p.id = :id
LIMIT 10;
```

Comment: thanks, will try now, quite confuse on inner join, so afterward the $result['user_image'] would be an array contain all images?

Comment: @geass, no the result will contain all the fields coming from the two tables which you selected `p.id, p.uid, p.content,
  i.filename, i.uid, i.pid`, you can select only what you want to select, and use the `WHERE` clause in the end to put your conditions.

Comment: erm...i tested and it totally get what i want.
but got another question, isit possible to run if else in mysql query?
the user_post got another field call type, if type 0 mean the post contain images, if type 1 mean the post don't have any images so no need to use INNER JOIN, isit possible to do if else inside query?

Comment: @geass - Yes, you can using the `CASE` expression like this `CASE WHEN type = 0 THEN ... ELSE ... END AS ..` But I didn't understand what do you want to select depending on that field `type`?

Comment: if field type = 0, mean the post contain images, have to run inner join,
if field type = 1, mean the post didnt have any images with it, so no need to run inner join

Comment: @geass, I think there is no need to do so, If there isn't related images in the other table the `INNER JOIN` won't get any thing. For those that has type = 1 there shouldn't any `pid` in the other table that relate to the `id` in the first table, so the `INNER JOIN` won't get that row, which will work fine. Is this right?

Comment: i tried, if the post don't have any images in the other table, the result get empty result array(0)

Comment: @geass, aha, in this case use `LEFT JOIN` instead of `INNER JOIN`.

Comment: thanks, shameful for asking these question, will go read more about mysql after this script done.

Comment: @geass - Sorry its my fault from beginning, I didn't understand you, see this blog post for more information about different sql joins types: http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/10/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins.html

Answer (score 0):

Simply, use an inner join. I haven't touched MySQL in a while, and it's been even longer with PHP, but I'll try to help:

```
SELECT `user_post`.*, `user_image`.* FROM `user_post` INNER JOIN ON `user_image`.`pid` = `user_post`.`id` WHERE `user_post`.`id` = :id
```

You'll want to set up a foreign key for this.